# Error response from daemon: Get https://xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v2/xxxx/manifests/v_50: no basic auth credentials

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, registry, docker-registry

I'm trying to implement CD/CI workflow with jenkins-docker-aws. I'm in the point of having the job properly configured but I'm getting an error at deployment time in ec2.

I face in AWS the following error:

> Status reason  CannotPullContainerError: API error (404): repository xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxx not found

My repository exists in AWS ECR. So, debugging and trying to pull the image that is in the Repository, I've executed the following commands to confirm everything is fine:

1.- Getting Logging succeeded by executing the output of:

> aws ecr get-login --no-include-email

2.- Checked my ~/.docker/config.json it shows, firstly it showed registry URL without protocol, but after reading some recomendations pointed to add it:

`{
        "auths": {
                "https://xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com": {
                        "auth": "long key..."
                }
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/17.12.1-ce (linux)"
        }
}`

So, after these checks and execute the pull command, I'm still getting...

> [ec2-user@ip-xxxxxx .docker]$ docker pull xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxx:v_50
>
> Error response from daemon: Get https://xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v2/davidtest/manifests/v_50: no basic auth credentials

Comment: facing the same issue while starting a service in ECS

Comment: @david M did you find the solution?